# Access Dictionary value by Array of keys

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift

I'm wondering if it's possible to, using Swift, get a value from a Dictionary using an Array as the key.

For example, say I wanted to get the image of a type of food, but only have the name of the food, like `apple`.

```
var foodImages = [
    ["orange", "apple", "banana", "kiwi"] : UIImage(named: "fruit"),
    ["steak", "burger", "ground beef"]    : UIImage(named: "beef"),
    ["carrots", "mushrooms", "potatoes"]  : UIImage(named: "vegetable"),
]
```

How would I get the image for `fruit` using `apple` from that Dictionary?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can (if it's an `NSArray`), but it's not going to be efficient...

The basic idea is to `filter` the keys of the `Dictionary` with a custom filter function which checks each key to see if it `contains` the item you're looking for. Then, since `filter` returns an `Array`, take the `first` item in the `Array` (if it exists) and use *that* as the key to get the actual value from the `Dictionary`.

On top of that, the only way you can use an `Array` as a key in a `Dictionary` is if it's an `NSArray`. Since it's an `NSArray`, your going to have to do some downcasting to get things to work right.

It would look something like this:

```
var foodImages = [
    ["orange", "apple", "banana", "kiwi"] : UIImage(named: "fruit"),
    ["steak", "burger", "ground beef"]    : UIImage(named: "beef"),
    ["carrots", "mushrooms", "potatoes"]  : UIImage(named: "vegetable"),
]

if let key = filter(foodImages.allKeys, { (list) -> Bool in
    let foodList = list as [String]
    return contains(foodList, "apple")
}).first as [String]? {
    if let image = foodImages[key] as UIImage? {
        /* use your image here */
    }
}
```

You could easily make that a function:

```
func getFoodImage(food: String) -> UIImage? {
    if let key = filter(foodImages.allKeys, { (list) -> Bool in
        let foodList = list as [String]
        return contains(foodList, food)
    }).first as [String]? {
        if let image = foodImages[key] as UIImage? {
            return image
        }
    }
    return nil
}

let image = getFoodImage("apple")
```

That being said, you're really not gaining anything by using an `NSArray` as a key to the `Dictionary`; it would be must better (and significantly more efficient) to just add each item in those `Array`s as their own key and store a `UIImage` as the value for each one. Since `UIImage` is a class, you'll be storing references to it and not copies, so there's not really an issue with memory usage.

```
var foodImages: [String: UIImage] = []

let fruitImage = UIImage(named: "fruit")
let beefImage = UIImage(named: "beef")
let vegetableImage = UIImage(named: "vegetable")

for food in ["orange", "apple", "banana", "kiwi"] {
    foodImages[food] = fruitImage
}

for food in ["steak", "burger", "ground beef"] {
    foodImages[food] = beefImage
}

for food in ["carrots", "mushrooms", "potatoes"] {
    foodImages[food] = vegetableImage
}
```

Then it's just the normal `Dictionary` subscript access:

```
let image = foodImages["apple"]
```

`image` will be `UIImage(named: "fruit")`

Answer (score 0):

No, because the keys have to be hashable.  You'll have to make each item as a different key:

```
var dict = [(String,String):String]()
dict["apple"] = "fruit"
dict["banana"] = "fruit"
```